# Can I save changed attributes of model after several set

Tags: backbone.js

I call `set` method multiple times and change several attributes. Then I want to send the changed data to the server with `{patch: true}`.

I can use `model.save(attrs, {patch: true});`, but I do not know `attrs`. I can't use `model.toJSON()` (unneeded fields) or `model.changedAttributes()` (only last set) to obtain `attrs`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you exactly want to send the server, only the changed attribute or all attributes present in model or some of attributes

Comment: Can you show us in example

Comment: Only changed attributes

Comment: You can bind listener on the model..... Listener function will be execute as soon as model value changes with changed attribute. You can send that to the server

Comment: For example:
Model is `{_id: 1, field1: 0, field2: 0, field3: 0}`
I execute
`model.set({field2: 2}); <...> model.set({field1: 1}); <...> model.save(...);`. I want to send to server `{field2: 2, field1: 1}`

Comment: There is a simpler solution, provided backbone.js?

Comment: Please look into my updated answer I think this is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`changedAttributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes):

> Optionally, an external attributes hash can be passed in, returning the attributes in that hash which differ from the model.

So you could try caching the state of model using [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) before you start modifying. Once your modifications are done, pass the new state to `changedAttributes` method to retrieve changed attributes hash and then send a patch request. Something like

```
var oldAttrs = model.toJSON();

// ...do modifications here

var changedAttrs = model.changedAttributes(oldAttrs);
dataTosend = model.pick(_.keys(changedAttrs));
model.save(dataTosend, {patch: true});
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that this is the most good way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a listener for model

If you are setting value in view, listener should be like (better write  it in initialize function)

```
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.onModelValueChange);
```

And your listener function

```
  onModelValueChange: function(model, args) {
      model.save(args.changed, {patch: true});
  }
```

Comment: But I want to call `save` only once

Comment: I think that it is necessary to create issue on the backbone github... To my opinion. I think it would be good if `save` without attrs on first parameter save all changed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

While [TJ has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41445360/1218980), I have a better way to achieve what he suggest.

Instead of making a raw clone of the attributes, I prefer to keep a *master* copy of the model at the start of the app or the initialize of the view.

```
this.master = this.model.clone();
// ... then changes are made to this.model
```

When ready to save, use the master model to compare the attributes and retrieve the changes directly.

```
var changes = this.master.changedAttributes(this.model.attributes);
if (changes !== false) this.model.save(changes, { patch: true });
```

With this, you can skip the `dataTosend = model.pick(_.keys(changedAttrs))` altogether since `changes` already is an object of all the differences with the initial state of the master model.

If it's a view that is re-used after the model save:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.updateMaster();
    },

    saveChanges: function() {
        var changes = this.master.changedAttributes(this.model.attributes);
        if (changes !== false) {
            this.model.save(changes, {
                patch: true,
                context: true,
                success: this.updateMaster
            });
        }
    },

    updateMaster: function() {
        this.master = this.model.clone();
    },
});
```